# Undefined interfaces during the pass to the template Angular8

Tags: angular, typescript, angular8

I am a novice with Angular8. 
I'm developing a template that passes an interface to another sub-micro-template and display it.
Main component template:

```
<evt-bibliography-item *ngFor="let biblCit of biblCits" 
                         biblField="{{ biblCit }}">
</evt-bibliography-item>
```

`biblCits` it is simply an array of interfaces obtained obtained with:

```
// main component ts.
this.bps.getBibliographicCitations().subscribe(response => {
      this.biblCits = response.citations;
```

So far everything is ok. The problem occurs when reading the single interface from the sub-component, which considers all the elements of the array `undefined`. 
This is the ts file:

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { BibliographicCitation } from 'src/app/services/xml-parsers/bibliography-parser.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'evt-bibliography-item',
  templateUrl: './bibliography-item.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./bibliography-item.component.scss']
})
export class BibliographyItemComponent {
  @Input() biblField: BibliographicCitation;

  constructor() {
    console.log(this.biblField)         // [Object Object]
    console.log(this.biblField.titles); // undefined
  }
}
```

Sub-template:

```
<p *ngFor="let biblEl of biblField | keyvalue">
  <em class="biblCitation">
    {{ biblEl.value }}
  </em>
</p>
```

Among the gimmicks I also tried `ngAfterViewInit` and `setInterval` without success. 
I can't understand why the elements are undefined. 
I hope it is nothing serious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not use the string interpolation (`{{}}`) when binding an object to an `@Input`, otherwise it will just call the `toString()` function on the object, and binds this to the input. You should use the square brackets (`[]`) for this. Check the [cheat sheet](https://angular.io/guide/cheatsheet) for more examples:

```
<evt-bibliography-item *ngFor="let biblCit of biblCits" 
                     [biblField]="biblCit">
</evt-bibliography-item>
```

The Input value will be available in your component in the [`ngOnInit`](https://angular.io/api/core/OnInit) hook:

```
ngOnInit() {
  console.log(this.biblField);
  console.log(this.biblField.titles);
}
```

> ngOnInit is a lifecycle hook that is called after Angular has initialized all data-bound properties of a directive

Answer (score 2):

I believe you need square brackets and no curly braces around your `biblField` in your html template. Try this:

```
<evt-bibliography-item *ngFor="let biblCit of biblCits" 
                         [biblField]="biblCit">
</evt-bibliography-item>
```